# Mysterious "ka-ching" sound coming from motherboard

Tags: motherboard, desktop-computer

I have noticed this sound coming from a desktop PC I have at home. I am 100% sure this is not coming from speakers, because I have disconnected them and tested. Also, this sound is coming out frequently even when the PC is in BIOS screen. The only time this sound stopped is after removing the GPU. I have replaced the GPU with a new one also, but still the sound is being produced. What could this mysterious sound be?

Comment: If you have a hard disk (not an SSD) and if the noise is coming from it, then backup your data quickly.

Comment: I have disconnected the HDD for 24 hours, and the sounds stopped coming out. Thanks

Comment: Even so, I suggest not to trust that disk with needed data that has no backup.

Comment: I have ordered a replacement HDD already, so that should be sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird noises coming from the computer are almost always caused by the hard disk,
and mean that the disk is close to failure.

The disk should not be used or powered on if it contains data without backup.

When a replacement disk is found, you may risk turning it on for just the time
that is required to get the data off it.

After the disk is all backed up, it should only be used for unimportant data
(or not at all).